# Displaying Errors Through actionFunction

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I have an APEX Page with a controller extension that collects a few fields of information from a user and creates a lead with a task when they click on the "Create Lead" button.

I have purposely made it so the saveLead method will fail, but I am not seeing the error messages in the page. Can someone explain why I am not seeing the error message?

Here is my VisualForce

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadCreationExtension">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, '/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, '/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"/>

<div class="bs">
<div class="container">
    <apex:form id="createLead">
        <apex:actionFunction name="saveLeadAndTask" action="{!saveLead}" reRender="createLead" focus="firstName" />

        <apex:pageBlock title="Create Lead" id="leadForm">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <p>To create a lead you must provide First Name, Last Name, Company and either a phone number or an email address</p>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons ><apex:commandButton title="Create Lead" styleClass="btn btn-success" value="Create" onclick="saveLeadAndTask();" /></apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.FirstName}" required="true" id="firstName"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.LastName}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Contact_Phone__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Email}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Sales_Segment__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Company}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Phone}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Website}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    </div>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

And the controller extension

```
public class LeadCreationExtension{
private final Lead ld;
private ApexPages.StandardController ctl;

public LeadCreationExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.ld = (Lead)stdController.getRecord();
    this.ctl = stdController;
}    

public PageReference saveLead(){
    SavePoint myRollback = Database.setSavepoint();

    PageReference saveResult;

    try{
        ld.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeCache.CacheByDeveloperName().get(RecordTypeCache.recordTypeLeadAcquire).id;
        ld.LeadSource = 'Rep Found';

        saveResult = ctl.save();

        //insert task
        Task myBookAppointmentTask = new Task();

        myBookAppointmentTask.Subject = 'Book Appointment';
        myBookAppointmentTask.CallType = 'Call';
        myBookAppointmentTask.OwnerId = System.UserInfo.getUserId();
        myBookAppointmentTask.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeCache.CacheByDeveloperName().get(RecordTypeCache.recordTypeAcquireInitialCallLead).id;
        myBookAppointmentTask.WhoId = ctl.getId();

        insert myBookAppointmentTask;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        Database.rollback(myRollback);
        saveResult = null;
    }
    return saveResult;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is something to do with the save method on the StandardController and the rollback.

I changed to use an insert and kept my rollback. Everything is working great now.

Here is my updated code

```
    SavePoint myRollback = Database.setSavepoint();

    PageReference saveResult;

    try{
        ld.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeCache.CacheByDeveloperName().get(RecordTypeCache.recordTypeLeadAcquire).id;
        ld.LeadSource = 'Rep Found';
        insert ld;

        //insert task
        Task myBookAppointmentTask = new Task();

        myBookAppointmentTask.Subject = 'Book Appointment';
        myBookAppointmentTask.Type = 'Call';
        myBookAppointmentTask.OwnerId = System.UserInfo.getUserId();
        myBookAppointmentTask.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeCache.CacheByDeveloperName().get(RecordTypeCache.recordTypeAcquireInitialCallLead).id;
        myBookAppointmentTask.WhoId = ld.id;

        insert myBookAppointmentTask;

        saveResult = new ApexPages.StandardController(ld).view();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        ld.id = null;
        Database.rollback(myRollback);
        saveResult = null;
    }
    return saveResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The possible flaw can be how your catch method is designed .

```
 catch(Exception e){
    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    Database.rollback(myRollback);//Dont Rollback on Error and add return
    saveResult = null;
}
```

One way this can be approached is as below

```
catch(Exception e){
    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    return null;
}
```